# Cambiar font size en Chart.js

Tags: chart.js

Como puedo cambiar el tamaño de la letra de un label en Chart.js?

[image: Adjunto imagen]

Comment: Bienvenida a StackOverflow. Es recomendable que leas el [Recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para que tus preguntas mejoren. Además, es muy recomendable que muestres el código con el que has avanzado para poder ayudar de una mejor manera.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Puedes modificar el tamaño estableciendo fontSize dentro de ticks que a su vez está dentro de scales en options. Por ejemplo:

```
var options = {
    scales: {
        xAxes: [{
            ticks: {
                fontSize: 40
            }
        }]
    }
}
```